# Javascript Engine V8 Fast property access

Tags: javascript, v8

When I look into the [v8 design elements of fast property access](https://developers.google.com/v8/design#prop_access), it mentions this point in the last paragraph for this topic:

> There are two advantages to using hidden classes: property access does
>   not require a dictionary lookup, and they enable V8 to use the classic
>   class-based optimization, inline caching.

This is a bit vague for me. Can anyone elaborate this on why hidden class does not require a dictionary lookup and enable v8 to use the classic class-based optimization, inline-caching?

Please do this as detail as possible.

Comment: "Can anyone elaborate this on why hidden class does not require a dictionary lookup" --- because there is no dictionary there. Read the "Fast Property Access" section once again

Comment: @Bergi: https://developers.google.com/v8/design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the idea of **hidden-classes** is well explained in the article you referred. Whenever a new property is added to an object a new *hidden-class* is created. The object keeps a reference to this hidden-class. In addition, the *hidden-class* also keeps a reference to the previously created *hidden-class*. For instance:

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var point = new Point(10, 10);
```

When `new Point()` is called a new *hidden-class* is created, and `point` keeps a reference to that *hidden-class*. That initial *hidden-class* is empty, that means, it contains no properties. Then, when `this.x` is called, a new *hidden-class* is created. That hidden class keeps a reference to the previous hidden class, and point updates its reference to that new *hidden-class*. The same happens again when `this.y = y` is executed.

As in JavaScript is possible to add and delete properties to an object dinamically, the way to resolve property access is by using a *map*. On the other hand, *hidden-classes* store properties linearly, one after another, like an *struct* in C. Thanks to *hidden-classes*, accessing a property is as fast as accessing an array's element.

Now let's take a look at what **inline caching** means. Inline caching is an old optimization technique, used in dynamic languages such as Smalltak 80 or Self and popularized by JavaScript. When a property is accessed at runtime, it is necessary to determine the type of the calling object in order to know exactly what implementation code to call. That is called *dynamic dispatch* or *late binding*, and is what happens in JavaScript when accessing a property or when summing up two operands (they could be *integer*, *double*, etc). Consider the following code:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 10;
var total = x + y;
```

When using *inline caching*, when `var total = x + y` is compiled, you don't compile in a procedure call to a generic addition subroutine. Instead, that code is compiled to a stub (the inline cache). The code generated in the *inline cache* takes a look at the types of the parameters received and generates code specialized for those types. Later, if another addition is called, the *inline cache* is executed assuming that the types will be the same as before. It could happen that the types were different though, thus the first thing an *inline cache* does is to check the types of the parameters. If the types are different that results into a *cache miss*, and new code is generated for those specific types. If the inline cache can handle many different types that is called a **polymorphic inline cache** (one with entries for more than one set of types).

*Inline caching* saves the computation of inferring the parameter types in a function call and their benefit is bigger if the call happens inside a loop for instance.

*Inline caching* happens in JavaScript while accessing the property of an object, and before we saw how *hidden-classes* can help us to have quick property access.

For more information about *hidden-classes* and *inline-caches* I recommend the following articles (specially the first two, from V8 hacker Vyacheslav Egorov):

- [V8 Inside Out](http://s3.mrale.ph/webrebels2012.pdf).
- [Explaining JavaScript VMs in JavaScript - Inline Caches](http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/06/03/explaining-js-vms-in-js-inline-caches.html).
- [Inline cache applications in scheme](http://wingolog.org/archives/2012/05/29/inline-cache-applications-in-scheme).
- [PICing on JavaScript for fun and profit](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/09/picing-on-javascript-for-fun-and-profit/).